# poll an http URL and show stats

Tags: javascript, open-source

I'm working on something where I need to poll an http URL and get the numbers available as part of the response and show graphical stats on a web page.

Does anyone know of any opensource software which can do something like this?

Sample URL:

http://dataqueue.com:8080/datamq/message/getcount?q=order.sales&class=com.xyz.entitiy.Order&metadata={}

which Results 15000

then another url would result 10000 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use plain Javascript to achieve something like this. Here's an example that does a server request every five seconds:

```js
function req() {
  fetch('http://reqres.in/api/users', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: 'morpheus',
      job: 'leader'
    })})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      document.getElementById('View').innerHTML =  json.id;
    });
}

req();
setInterval(() => req(), 5000);
```

```html
<div id="View"></div>
```

There are also libraries that make this easier, for example [PollJS](https://github.com/mtrpcic/polljs). You can find more on Github. If you have control over the server, you might want to check out [Socket.io](http://socket.io).